# Using X11-Forwarding to show UI that runs by different user

Tags: terminal, applications, user-account, ui, x11

I've logged on to my Mac under 'user1', and opened a terminal in which I've switched to another user 'user2' using `su` command.

Now I've opened a `.txt` file from that terminal by typing `open file.txt` which spawned the TextEdit application.

However, its UI couldn't be shown since I've logged-in with a different user (user1) ..

Is there a way to re-direct the UI of TextEdit to 'user1'. I know that in Linux there's X11-Forwarding but is it also supported in macOS ?

Comment: Simple answer is no - although you can do that with X11 apps which you would have to compile yorself

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment.. What exactly do I need to compile, the app that I want to use or X11 for Mac ?

Comment: The app - [Xquartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) supplies X11. But most apps including TextEdit are not X11 and so can't be done you can only use software recompiled from other Unices. Also easiest to use a package manager like Macports or Homebrew.